# Подогнать высоту контейнера под дочек css

Tags: html, css

подскажите, как подогнать высоту контейнера под меню, которое выпадает справа?

```js
$('body').on('click', '.btn-dropdown', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('.btn-menu').toggleClass('open');
  $('.navigation--catalog').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
header .bottom__header .bottom__header--box {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header .bottom__header .bottom__header--box .btn-dropdown {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-right: 50px;
  min-width: -webkit-max-content;
  min-width: -moz-max-content;
  min-width: max-content;
}

header .bottom__header .bottom__header--box .btn-dropdown:hover,
header .bottom__header .bottom__header--box .btn-dropdown.active {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FF4764;
}

.navigation--catalog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 164px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 28px 0;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #ccc;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30px) translateX(0);
  transform: translateY(30px) translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  transition: 0.3s all cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}

.navigation--catalog.open {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);
  transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navigation--catalog .container-fluid {
  position: relative;
}

.navigation--catalog .parent_nav {
  width: 300px;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #DCECF4;
}

.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li {
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li.parent.dropdown {
  position: inherit;
}

.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li.parent.open .parent-a a {
  color: #FF4764;
}

.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li.parent.open .parent-a .icon-arrow svg {
  fill: #FF4764;
  stroke: #FF4764;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  transform: rotate(-270deg);
}

.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li.parent:hover .parent-a a {
  color: #FF4764;
}

.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li.parent:hover .parent-a .icon-arrow svg {
  fill: #FF4764;
  stroke: #FF4764;
}

.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li .parent-a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li .parent-a .icon-arrow svg {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li a {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li .sub {
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 436px;
  top: 0;
  min-width: -webkit-max-content;
  min-width: -moz-max-content;
  min-width: max-content;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li .sub.dropdown {
  position: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Последняя компиляция и сжатый CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Дополнение к теме -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Последняя компиляция и сжатый JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<header>
  <div class="bottom__header">
    <div class="bottom__header--box">
      <div class="btn-category">
        <div class="btn-dropdown">
          <div class="btn-menu">
            <span class="_line __1"></span>
            <span class="_line __2"></span>
          </div>
          Все категории
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation--catalog">
    <div class="container-fluid p-136">
      <ul class="parent_nav">
        <li class="parent dropdown">

          <div class="parent-a" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Для женщин</a>

            <div class="icon-arrow"><svg><use xlink:href="#carret"></use></svg></div>
          </div>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu sub">
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_410">Аксессуары</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_417">Боди, торсеты и грации</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_403">Бюстгальтеры</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/dlya-zhenschin/domashnyaya-odezhda">Домашняя одежда</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_397">Жакеты женские оптом</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_406">Женские трусы</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_416">Купальники</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_384">Майки и футболки</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_388">Ночные сорочки</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_390">Пижамы</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_389">Пляжная одежда</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_404">Трусы утягивающие</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/dlya-zhenschin/fitnes">Фитнес</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_387">Халаты для дома</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_398">Эротическое нижнее белье</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=421_394">Юбки женские</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="parent dropdown">

          <div class="parent-a" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Для мужчин</a>

            <div class="icon-arrow"><svg><use xlink:href="#carret"></use></svg></div>
          </div>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu sub">
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=423_402">Мужские брюки и шорты</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=423_400">Мужские костюмы для дома и отдыха</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://extremje.bget.ru/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=423_385">Мужской верхний трикотаж</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: "дочек" - это дочерние элементы?

Comment: да, в выпадающем меню, при клике на "Для женщин" например

Comment: Не задавайте ему `height`, она будет автоматически вычисляться браузером, или поставьте `height: auto`.

Comment: не стоит ведь нигде height

Comment: Почему вы много раз переопределяете `display`?

Comment: а это влияет на что-то? я просто для примера показал, мне нужно чтобы при клике по "для женщин"  серый блок охватывал подменю

Comment: Лучше, конечно, в будущем выкладывайте css до autoprefixer-а. Код трудно читаем

Comment: хорошо, на будущее принял

Comment: а можно что-нибудь сделать с моей ситуацией?

Comment: Пока-что ничего умнее чем: `.dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: static !important;
  transform: translateX(500px);
}`

Answer (score 0):

сделал так

```
let h_parent = $('.navigation--catalog').height();


if (screen.width > '1380') {
        $('body').on('click','.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li.parent .parent-a', function(){
            let hg = $(this).closest('.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li.parent').find('.sub').height();
            $('.navigation--catalog').height(hg);
        });
        $('body').on('click','.navigation--catalog .parent_nav li.parent.open .parent-a', function(){
            $('.navigation--catalog').height(h_parent);
```

});
    }